# In Android how to know when a DatagramPacket has been received?

Tags: android, qt, sockets, packet, datagram

Assume that a transmitter is sending DatagramPacket at random intervals. Is there a way to know when a packet is received at the receiver?
In C++ and using QT it is possible to `connect` the socket to a `readyRead()` signal for example:

```
connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
```

Then everytime a packet is arraived at receiver a `SIGNAL` is emitted and we jump to `processPendingDatagrams()` routine.

Is it possible to do something similar in Android?
If not what is the best way to read received packets as soon as they arrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you must implement your own thread witch waits until there is a datagram packet aviable .You can send a message to the main thread using a handler.

A good tutorial on how to do this you can find [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-udp-communication-example).